# How to Set the fetch size in Slick?

Tags: scala, slick, slick-3.0

I am trying to find out how to instruct slick to use a specific fetch size, but can't find it. Does anyone has an idea ? Also what logger needs to be set to see that indeed a different fetch size is being used ?

Does the fetch size applies only to Streaming Action or also to non-Streaming Action ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an extension method for DB Action:

```
def withStatementParameters(rsType: ResultSetType = null, rsConcurrency: ResultSetConcurrency = null, rsHoldability: ResultSetHoldability = null, statementInit: Statement => Unit = null, fetchSize: Int = 0): DBIOAction[R, S, E] = ...
```

where  `fetchSize` is the fetch size for all statements.